# extraneous input 'visible' found, expecting ')'

Tags: mysql

[image: 1]

I am having this issue, while importing mysql file ?
how can i resolve it ?

Comment: It seems that your Workbench version does not match server version...

Comment: We can't help much with just image, we need to see file. Syntax error is the possibility at line 22. You can check exact line numbers and accordingly verify 1-2 lines above and down of mentioned line numbers in error message.